# Using blue tooth or wireless wifi to send audio to camera from recorder

Tags: audio, camera

Does anyone have any information regarding issues sending audio from a sound device 722 to camera via a wireless wifi transmitter/ receiver or via bluetooth.

The reason for my question is that my research may have dug up some issues with latency whereby both units send data, not audio to the receiver and it needs to be unpackaged and checked for errors before being converted back to audio which may cause latency of anywhere between 1 frame and 4 frames making the venture redundant. What's the use of sending audio to camera if it is in danger of being out of sync with the image?

Does anyone use such a system and if so does it work or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Neither of those wireless protocols will come close to the latency of Radio Frequency wireless audio used by traditional wireless mic systems to be used for real time recording unfortunately.

Even this "low latency" codec advertises 40ms which isn't good for recording in my opinion.

I recommend something like these instead: http://www.fullcompass.com/category/Plug-In-Wireless-Transmitters-Only.html

Answer (score 1):

Generally this kind of thing is avoided because of latency and drop out issues. The issue here is that the audio comes from the source, is digitally encoded, transmitted, then decoded. That whole process takes time. Even the fastest systems have lag. A traditional wireless system that broadcasts over radio is limited only by the speed the radio waves can travel though the air and a bit by the electronics but again not much. I would not advise trying this, get a good wireless mic, even the less expensive ones are good quality these days.